# handling runtime inputs in processbuilder

Tags: java, cmd, runtime, processbuilder

Presently, I am working on a particular requirement where I need to execute a command on the underlying system using ProcessBuilder. Till now the case was simply limited to supplying commands to a ProcessBuilder instance along with the working directory. Now, I need to handle cases where a command's execution hangs up expecting a user's response to proceed further with the execution. Usually, the execution throws up some custom questions which the user needs to answer to proceed further.

I can't be really sure about the questions or the sequence in which they are asked, hence, passing an additional parameter in the ProcessBuilder is not an option.

How do we handle such scenarios ? Does ProcessBuilder throw some events to notify of such temporary halts ? Is there any other approach which helps with this particular case (If ProcessBuilder can not handle the job)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read from the process's output stream using [Process.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and respond to the process using it's input stream ([Process.getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29)).